# Setting websocket SSL on grizzly

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, tyrus

I'm trying to configure a WebSocket over SSL with the "javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint" on a grizzly container. However i can't find any way to set the SSL property to my endpoint.

My endpoint code :

```
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(
    Value="/ptiWs",
    decoders = {ApiMessage.ApiCoder.class},
)
public class WebsocketEndpoint {

   private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(WebsocketEndpoint.class);
   private final ApiVisitorImpl apiVisitor;

    public WebsocketEndpoint(){
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        LOG.info("New connection open : " + session.toString());
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void message(Session session, ApiMessage message){
        LOG.info("New message arrive " + message.toString());
    }
}
```

Finally, I add my endpoint to my Grizzly instance with the following code :

```
Server ptiWebsocket = new Server("localhost", 8025, "/", null, WebsocketEndpoint.class);
ptiWebsocket.start();
```

I have already done this work for glassfish and it's pretty easy, but here i don't find any way to proceed.

And the dependency :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you are using Jetty? This seems more like built-in grizzly container support which is shipped with Tyrus.

Comment: You have right, Jetty has no report with this problem. That's effectively a grizzly container. I edit the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the tyrus source code, it looks like that this isn't supported out of the box. You'll need to make a new ServerContainerFactory much like the  org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerContainer. Go grab the code out of Github. You can make your own GrizzlySSLServerContainer. And then you'll add the SSL config to the NetworkListener in the start method. You can then add the full qualified name of your new GrizzlySSLServerContainer class into a META-INF/services/org.glassfish.tyrus.spi.ServerContainerFactory with your JAR and Tyrus should pick it up.

It is somewhat hacky, and it sucks to have to copy/paste code but it should work.

1.) Copy GrizzlyServerContainer to your new GrizzlySSLServerContainer class.

2.) Add method to provide SSL configuration data into your new Container class.

3.) Add data to NetworkListener to instantiate SSL

4.) Add your new class to the META-INF/serivces directory of your jar.

Comment: As I suspect no native support for websocket ssl :( I have change technology for my project, so I will not test your solution but this must work. Thanks

Comment: Has anyone already done this successfully?  I'm working on a POC that uses Tyrus and Grizzly standalone, and need it to be SSL.  Found out here in the 11th hour; no SSL support ("wss") in the Grizzly container!  What the heck?!

Comment: Any one did it ?

Comment: Still doesn't appear possible to do this, even though Tyrus is the RI of Java WebSockets. I've posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849572/how-can-i-programmatically-enable-wss-for-a-tyrus-websocket-serverendpoint

Comment: This worked - see my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867046/17641